# Angular UI router; how to not match empty parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My website has 2 main routes:

```
/home
/:something
```

Any request to / should go to /home and this is done by using 'otherwise', anything else that does not match home AND is not empty should go to app.lista. The thing is, app.lista matches / because is like :slug is empty, so otherwise is not being called:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: '/',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: '/_/common/templates/main.html',
      controller: 'main'
    })
    .state('app.home', {
      url: 'home',
      views: {
        sectionHolder: {
          templateUrl: '/_/home/templates/home.html',
          controller: 'home'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.lista', {
      url: ':slug',
      views: {
        sectionHolder: {
          templateUrl: '/_/home/templates/list.html',
          controller: 'list'
        }
      }
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

How can I tell the stateProvider to not match app.lista if :slug is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like same issue which is logged [Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3284) on github and solution seems to be the use ragular expression

I think changing  your `slug route` to

```
.state('app.lista', {
      url: '/{slag:[^\/]+}',
      views: {
        sectionHolder: {
          templateUrl: '/_/home/templates/list.html',
          controller: 'list'
        }
      }
    });
```

Should solve your problem [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/anpfvTPYJqfALVyuBCbZ?p=preview)

Comment: Your plunkr works when you navigate to `/` from `route1` but breaks when you navigate from `route2`

Answer (score 0):

Make your app route non-abstract and change the template and controller to point to that of `app.home`. Since it is defined before `app.list`, `'/'` will match `app` route instead.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: '/_/common/templates/home.html',
      controller: 'home'
    })
    .state('app.home', {
      url: 'home',
      views: {
        sectionHolder: {
          templateUrl: '/_/home/templates/home.html',
          controller: 'home'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.lista', {
      url: ':slug',
      views: {
        sectionHolder: {
          templateUrl: '/_/home/templates/list.html',
          controller: 'list'
        }
      }
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UI Routers [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) to check if route params are missing.

```
//Example of a single route
.state('app.lista', {
  url: '/:slug',
  templateUrl: '----.html',
  controller: 'list',
  resolve: function($stateParams, $location){

    //Check if url parameter is missing.
    if ($stateParams.slug=== undefined) {
      //Do something such as navigating to a different page.
      $location.path('/somewhere/else');
    }
  }
})
```